# Query string safety and variable interpolation

Tags: php, string-interpolation

Not very familiar with PHP, is it possible for the user to take advantage of variable interpolation to get the value of secret?

```
<?php 
    $secret = 'hidden data';
    echo $_GET['id'];
?>
```

I tried passing in for the id: $secret, %24secret, ${secret}, {$secret}, %7D%24secret%7D, %24%7Dsecret%7D. So far it seems safe, but just want to make sure I am not missing anything. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If such a thing was possible, I don't think there would have been *so many* web applications written in php. Also `$_GET` is an array and eventually you'd have `$_GET[$secret]`, so if the value of `$secret` isn't a valid array key of `$_GET`, there still would be no problem.

Comment: It's not possible, unless you accidentally write `$$_GET['id']`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's impossible for a user to retrieve hard-coded strings in this way.

Answer (score 1):

No.

But use `htmlentities($_GET["id"])` anyway because  otherwise we can use cross-site scripting attacks (steal login cookies, session data, etc).